# C# Chart - data is repeated

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

I have the following Data (from the database):

[image]

These are stored in objects that are stored in a list:

for creating the chart series i have created the following function:

```
public void CreateSeries(DateTime seriesTime)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (seriesTime.Date > _stopDate.Date) return;
        foreach (var data in _datalist)
        {
            var currentData = (Email)data;
            String xLabel;
            switch (_timeType)
            {
                case DateUtils.TimeType.Weeks:
                    xLabel = seriesTime.Date.ToString("dd");
                    break;
                case DateUtils.TimeType.Months:
                    xLabel = seriesTime.Date.ToString("MM");
                    break;
                case DateUtils.TimeType.Years:
                    xLabel = seriesTime.Date.ToString("yyyy");
                    break;
                default:
                    xLabel = seriesTime.Date.ToString("dd");
                    break;
            }
            AddData(currentData, xLabel);
        }

        if (DateConverter.GetDaysBetween(seriesTime, _stopDate) >= 0)
        {
            seriesTime = AppendDays(seriesTime);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}

protected DateTime AppendDays(DateTime initialDateTime)
{
    switch (_timeType)
    {
        case DateUtils.TimeType.Weeks:
            initialDateTime = initialDateTime.AddDays(7);
            break;
        case DateUtils.TimeType.Months:
            initialDateTime = initialDateTime.AddMonths(1);
            break;
        case DateUtils.TimeType.Years:
            initialDateTime =  initialDateTime.AddYears(1);
            break;
        default:
            initialDateTime = initialDateTime.AddDays(1);
            break;
    }
    return initialDateTime;
}
```

All of which executes without any issues.

Then when the series have been added i use the following loop in my Form class:

```
List<Series> chart = ((EmailModel)_controller.GetFactory().GetModel("Email")).GetEmailChart(from, to, current_timetype);
test_chart.Series.Clear();
foreach (Series s in chart)
{
    test_chart.Series.Add(s);
}
```

Which produces the following chart:

[image]

if you look closely then you will see that it has repeated the data 7 times.

i just don't know what the issue is.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Please tell me if you need more info or code i will check back every often and update my question.

Comment: I just began reading your code, but couldn't foreach at the end simply be replaced with `test_chart.Series = chart`?

Comment: Error 1 Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Series' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Where do you call `CreateSeries()`? What is `_dataList` / where is it filled? How many times does the `foreach` loop in `CreateSeries()` get iterated?

Answer (score 0):

As i see the partern you repeat 7 times 7 column.
You have to add 1 serie.
Try:
 test_chart.Series.Add(s);

Whitout the foreach!

Comment: The foreach loop is to get each of the series out of the list. i am unable to use the code you are suggesting. Also using the debugger the foreach loop only runs 3 times (as it should)